# How to generate custom Thumbnail image of an image in WinRT? Looking for an algorithm similar to StorageFile.GetThumbnailAsync

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, windows-10, winrt-async

I ran into an issue when i tried to access the thumbnail image of a file which is in local storage of the app(due to access issues). And the workaround suggesting :

1.copying the file to public directory

2.get thumbnail image

3.delete file from public directory

was helpful but slow when thumbnails of several files were required.

Any idea(algorithm) on how the thumnail generation api of WinRt works would help.

Answer (score 0):

This Task should create from image file 5 times smaller thumbnail file:

```
        private async Task SaveImageAsync(StorageFile inputFile, StorageFile outputFile)
    {
            Guid encoderId = BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId;

            using (IRandomAccessStream inputStream = await inputFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read),
                       outputStream = await outputFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
            {
                outputStream.Size = 0;

                BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(inputStream);
                BitmapTransform transform = new BitmapTransform();

                double scalefactor = 0.2;  // 5 times smaller

                transform.ScaledHeight = (uint)(decoder.PixelHeight * scalefactor);
                transform.ScaledWidth = (uint)(decoder.PixelWidth * scalefactor);

                transform.InterpolationMode = BitmapInterpolationMode.Fant;

                BitmapPixelFormat format = decoder.BitmapPixelFormat;
                BitmapAlphaMode alpha = decoder.BitmapAlphaMode;

                PixelDataProvider pixelProvider = await decoder.GetPixelDataAsync(format, alpha, transform,
                    ExifOrientationMode.RespectExifOrientation, ColorManagementMode.ColorManageToSRgb);

                byte[] pixels = pixelProvider.DetachPixelData();

                BitmapEncoder encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(encoderId, outputStream);
                encoder.SetPixelData(
                    format,
                    alpha,
                    (uint)((double)decoder.PixelWidth * scalefactor),
                    (uint)((double)decoder.PixelHeight * scalefactor),
                    decoder.DpiX,
                    decoder.DpiY,
                    pixels
                    );

                await encoder.FlushAsync();
            }
    }
```